# View updates to React and Flask Fullstack in Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flask, npm

I am new to working with React and Flask and I started by following this tutorial https://codeburst.io/creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-python-npm-webpack-and-react-8925800503d9 and completed building the example fullstack website. My code is an exact copy of the code in the author's example at their github page here https://github.com/angineering/FullStackTemplate. However, when I change anything in the files, rebuild the project, start the server.py file, and open the server port on my browser in a new tab at http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ...nothing changes or updates. If I change the text name from "Remini" to "Kai" and rebuild and reload, the web app still runs "Hello Rimini".

I've tried closing the server and reopening, restarting Chrome, and rebuilding, but nothing changed. When I open the server in firefox no data is loaded at all, not the index page or the background image. And when I view source on Chrome, I can see changes I made before the build such as adding html elements, so I know the build was successful, but the name text doesn't change. Also, if I add another background image and change the css to load the alternative image, the original image still loads as the background image.

I think this is an issue with the server and the browser, and can't figure out how to connect to the right port to load the changes to the javascript (in this case jsx). My question is, how do I build this React/Flask web app project using npm and get my browser to reflect my changes to the project in the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem. Chrome was caching the site, and when I opened developer tools and right clicked the reload button to "clear cache and hard reload" the correct and updated build loaded.

Comment: CTRL+Refresh works in Chrome too, I believe. It clears the cache and reloads.